# Visual Studio URL ReWrite

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, visual-studio

I am wanting to rewrite .aspx pages in Visual Studio to .html pages throughout the entire solution.

Is there an easy way to do this using the web.config file or .htaccess file?

Comment: Use IIS using URL Rewrite.

Comment: Is this something I can do in Visual Studio? I ask as I am a front end designer instead of a developer.

Comment: http://urlrewriter.net/ works in web.config, just drop the DLL in.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by writing rules for rewrite in web config file

```
<urlrewrites>
            <rule>
                <url>/urlrewriter/show\.asp</url>
                <rewrite>show.aspx</rewrite>
            </rule>
            <rule>
                <url>/urlrewriter/wohs\.asp</url>
                <rewrite>show.aspx</rewrite>
            </rule>
            <rule>
                <url>/urlrewriter/show(.*)\.asp</url>
                <rewrite>show.aspx?$1</rewrite>
            </rule>
            <rule>
                <url>/urlrewriter/(.*)show\.html</url>
                <rewrite>show.aspx?id=$1&amp;cat=2</rewrite>
            </rule>
            <rule>
                <url>/urlrewriter/s/h/o/w/(.*)\.html</url>
                <rewrite>/urlrewriter/show.aspx?id=$1</rewrite>
            </rule>
        </urlrewrites>
```

and also you can do this using dll for rewrite, but rules are mandatory for rewrite.

Thank you.

Comment: SO my web config file looks like this:

Comment: <?xml version="1.0"?><configuration><system.web><compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" /><httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" /><urlrewrites>
<rule><url>/urlrewriter/show\.asp</url><rewrite>show.aspx</rewrite>
</rule><rule><url>/urlrewriter/wohs\.asp</url><rewrite>show.aspx</rewrite></rule><rule>
<url>/urlrewriter/show(.*)\.asp</url><rewrite>show.aspx?$1</rewrite>
</rule><rule><url>/urlrewriter/(.*)show\.html</url><rewrite>show.aspx?id=$1&amp;cat=2</rewrite></rule>
<rule><url>/urlrewriter/s/h/o/w/(.*)\.html</url><rewrite>

Comment: /urlrewriter/show.aspx?id=$1</rewrite></rule></urlrewrites>
</system.web></configuration>

Comment: I get this error: 
HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.

Comment: Please read this article this will show how to make url rewrite working http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx you need to use Intelligencia.UrlRewriter.dll